# Авторизация на ВКонтакте

Tags: php

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на ВКонтакте скриптом на php, до определённого момента всё идёт гладко, но потом появляется ошибка 400 Bad Request.

Суть в том, что на последнем шаге остается спарсить ссылку, что скрипт успешно делает, и перейти по ней. Тут-то и появляется ошибка 400, ведь если просто скопировать ссылку и перейти по ней - авторизация проходит.

```
<?
$curl = curl_init();

$browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0';

$data = [
            'email' => 'email@site.com'
            ,'pass' => 'password'
        ];
// подготовительные данные

$options = [
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT          => $browser
                ,CURLOPT_URL               => 'http://m.vk.com'
                ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1
                ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30
            ];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// запрос делаем на мобильную версию ВКонтакте

preg_match('/ip\_h\=(.*?)\&/is', $response, $match);

$ip_h = $match[1];
// парсим ip_h

$url = 'https://login.vk.com/?act=login&_origin=http://m.vk.com&ip_h='.$ip_h.'&role=pda&utf8=1';
// формируем url

$options = [
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT          => $browser
                ,CURLOPT_URL               => $url
                ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS        => http_build_query($data)
                ,CURLOPT_POST              => 1
                ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1
                ,CURLOPT_HEADER            => 1
                ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => 0
                ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST    => 0
                ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30
            ];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// делаем запрос на сформированный url

preg_match('/Location: (.*?)\n/is', $response, $match);

$url = $match[1];
/*
  парсим оттуда ссылку на которую нас должно перебросить
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION не включил, т.к так удобнее/
  Что интересно, если эту ссылку вывести на данном этапе,
  то перейдя по ней авторизация пройдёт до конца,
  и пользователь оказывается в своей новостной ленте.
  Ссылка вида
  http://m.vk.com/login?role=fast&to=&s=1&__q_hash=4baa84d796ed6a2d826ace41508614eb
  После запроса возвращается нужная кука и происходит переадресация на /
  Пробовал с абсолютно чистого браузера(открывал режим инкогнито),
  авторизация всё равно проходит до конца.
  Для того что-бы исключить фактор IP адреса, пробовал развернуть
  Open Server на своём ПК - результат такой же.
*/

$options = [
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT          => $browser
                ,CURLOPT_URL               => $url
                ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1
                ,CURLOPT_HEADER            => 1
                ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30
            ];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// делаем запрос на нужный url

echo $response;
// результат - 400 Bad Request

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: А если смотреть в инспекторе, никаких дополнительных параметров не передается?

Comment: Можно через api, grant_type=password